# In Fat Free Framework how can I define an ONERROR route in routes.ini

Tags: php, url-routing, fat-free-framework

I know I can do this:

```
$f3->set('ONERROR',function($f3){
  echo \Template::instance()->render('error.html');
});
```

I want to work in routes.ini, is it possible to define it there?

```
; Process login form submission
GET|POST /login="Controllers\Main->login"
; Logout
GET /logout="Controllers\Main->logout"

;Errors
ONERROR="Controllers\Main->error"
```

Comment: the irony of any framework being called 'fat-free'

Comment: its actually very slim and efficient, a great framework with an apropos name, but this is not a political debate :)  what do you think about Slim? http://www.slimframework.com/  lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't be defined as a route but it can be defined in the same file. Since your "routes.ini" is simply a config file which is loaded by F3's `config()`, you can do something like

```
[routes]
; Process login form submission
GET|POST /login="Controllers\Main->login"
; Logout
GET /logout="Controllers\Main->logout"

[globals]
;Errors
ONERROR="Controllers\Main->error"
```

You can read more about it here: https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree#configuration-files

Comment: thanks. i didnt know i could specify a controller function in a global  variable. very smart. f34ever! :)